# warning count() parameter must be an array or an object that implements countable in

Tags: php

En la línea:

`($i-0; $i<count($array['servicios']); $i++)`

Es donde me da un problema porque si pongo is empty o countable el error desaparece pero no cuenta los otros registros más que uno.

```
public function __construct($array = null){
    if($array){
        if($array['id']){
            $this->setId($array['id']);
        }
        $this->setFecha($array['fecha']);
        $aux = ($array['pesoMascota'])? $array['pesoMascota'] : 0;
        $this->setPesoMascota($aux);
        $this->setIdMascota($array['id_mascota']);
        $this->setIdVeterinario($_SESSION['veterinario']['id']);
        $this->setExterno( ($array['externo'] == ('on' || 1))? 1 : 0 );
        $aux = array();
        for ($i=0; $i<count($array['servicios']);$i++){ 
            $aux[$i]['id_servicio'] = $array['servicios'][$i];
            $aux[$i]['observacion'] = $array['observaciones'][$i];
            $aux[$i]['precioSugerido'] = $array['preciosSugeridos'][$i];
        }
        $this->setItemsConsulta($aux);
    }
}
array(7) á ["id"]> string(1) "1" ["id_mascota"]-> string(1) "6" ["id_veterinario"]-> string(1) "1" ["fecha"]> string(10) "2020-08-11" ["externo"]> string(1) "1" ["pesoMascota"]> string(2) "22" ["eliminado"]> string(1) "0"
```

Comment: El mensaje es claro, en `$array['servicios']` no hay un array ni ningún objeto que se pueda contar. Para revisar la estructura con la que estás trabajando puedes hacer un `var_dump($array);`

Comment: me salio esto array(7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["id_mascota"]=> string(1) "6" ["id_veterinario"]=> string(1) "1" ["fecha"]=> string(10) "2020-08-11" ["externo"]=> string(1) "1" ["pesoMascota"]=> string(2) "22" ["eliminado"]=> string(1) "0" }

Comment: No hay ni siquiera una clave `servicios` en la cual a su vez debería haber un array al cual podrías aplicarle `count`, no sé si queda claro lo que te quiero decir. Debes revisar lo que estás obteniendo o bien explícanos lo que quieres hacer en ese bucle `for`